# Unable to run java code with selenium webdriver and automate the the browser by using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I tried to run the below code and list of errors were thrown.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class AyeshaDemo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Course\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");       
    }
}
```

```
Error--
Starting ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135}) on port 10094
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Sep 14, 2021 3:09:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1631612667.173][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
[1631612667.179][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'AYESHA-NEWRL', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 93.0.4577.63, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0ad..., userDataDir: C:\Users\AYESHA~1.SHE\AppDa...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54098}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: eb574d06cc154c124dc1ba2425e853c4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at AyeshaDemo1.main(AyeshaDemo1.java:11)**
```

Comment: What is your chrome driver version ?

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: ChromDriver -- Version 93.0.4577.63